# JDK cannot be opened after MacOS upgraded to 10.15.X (Catalina)

Tags: macos-catalina

After MacOS is upgraded to 10.15.X (Catalina), JDK cannot be opened. The message shows "JDK cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified".

Answer (score 0):

According to [java.com](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/catalina_java.xml):

> Changes introduced with macOS 10.15 (Catalina) cause certain Java
>   applications to behave incorrectly. Therefore, we cannot certify any
>   JDK version on macOS 10.15 yet. However, as of now, you can install
>   and run non-notarized software on macOS 10.15 systems by modifying
>   your security preferences.

You can find detailed information about it [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/using-jdk-jre-macos-catalina-5781620.html).